# how to pass data to php using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to display a message according to the className passed to server using AJAX . I'm new ajax , I have no idea about that..

myhtml code :

```
<div class="header">
        <h2>Configuration</h2>
        <p> Enable: </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off " id="enable-btn"></i>
        <span id="demo">Dashboard Enabled</span>
    </div>
```

myJS code :

```
function enableButtonClicked() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#enable-btn').click(function () {
            $( ".dashboard, #demo" ).toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass("fa-toggle-off fa-toggle-on");
        });
    }); 
}
```

ajax code :

```
function displayMessageAccordingToButtonState() {
    var x = document.getElementById('enable-btn').className;
    if( x == 'fas fa-toggle-off'){
        var msg = "Button Disabled"
        $('.header').load('request.php',{"displayMsg":msg});
    }
    else {
        var msg = "Button Enabled"
        $('.header').load('request.php',{"displayMsg":msg});
    }

}
```

php code :

```
<?php
   if( $_REQUEST["displayMsg"] ){
      $msg = $_REQUEST['displayMsg'];
      echo "".$msg ;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Read $.ajax method in jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: use two different pages simple or send some data to check in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working demo

just copy and try

i have added extra span and ajax file content is copy to that content

```
 <html>
      <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      </head>
      <body>

      <div class="header">
         <h2>Configuration</h2>
         <p> Enable: </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off " id="enable-btn"></i>
         <span id="demo">Dashboard Enabled</span>
     </div>
    <span id="demo2"></span>
      </body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">          </script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#enable-btn').click(function () {
        $( ".dashboard, #demo" ).toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-toggle-off fa-toggle-on");
    });
}); 


 $('#enable-btn').click(function () {   
 var x = document.getElementById('enable-btn').className;    
 if( x == 'fas fa-toggle-off'){
    var msg = "Button Disabled"
    $('#demo2').load('request.php',{"displayMsg":msg},function(responseTxt,      statusTxt, xhr){
    if(statusTxt == "success")
        console.log("External content loaded successfully!"+responseTxt);
    if(statusTxt == "error")
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
}
else {
    var msg = "Button Enabled"
            $('#demo2').load('request.php',{"displayMsg":msg},function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    if(statusTxt == "success")
        console.log("External content loaded successfully!"+responseTxt);
    if(statusTxt == "error")
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
}
 });
 </script>
 </html>
```

this is my php file

```
  if( $_REQUEST["displayMsg"] ){
     $msg = $_REQUEST['displayMsg'];
     echo "".$msg ;
  }
```

Comment: console saying $load is not  afunction

Comment: please check  jquery file is linked or not ? i have successfully tested this code

Comment: can u provide php code also or you are using the same as mine?

Comment: its saying Notice: Undefined index: displayMsg in C:\xampp\htdocs\Custom Dashboard\request.php on line 2

Comment: check your php file variables or copy my file code which i have pasted

Answer (score 0):

in JS

```
var request = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'Php.file', / your php file path
        type: "POST",
        data: "Value1=your value";
        datatype: 'html',
    });
    request.done(function(data) {
        //data you will handle from php file
    });
```

in PHP receive

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
  //you can check like this
  if(empty($data))
  {
    echo("none received");
  }
  else{
   echo 'passed parameter '+$data;
   //in here you will receive as data in js file
you will receive in data in js as 'passed parameter+ your value'
  }
```

Comment: how do i pass my element's class name to php? like data :  "value1 = enable-btn.className " ?

Comment: Yes @AnamolShrestha your right 'value1=enable-btn.className'

Comment: its saying $ajax is not a function

Comment: $.ajax not $ajax

Comment: also did you add your jquery library into your html?

Answer (score 0):

First of all is to create an HTML file with jQuery included.

Let's say you have a hidden input field.

`<input type="hidden" id="mydata" value="sampledata">`

You can now get the data from the hidden field using the script `$("#mydata").val();`

You can now write the ajax code as follows

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'post',
  url: '/path/to/ajax.php',
  data: {
    postvariable: $("#mydata").val()
  },
  success: function() {
    alert('success');
  }
});
```

In your ajax.php file, you can now receive the value as `$_POST['postvariable']`

You can now declare 
`$myphpvar = $_POST['postvariable'];`

Where
`echo $myphpvar; //will print 'sampledata' without quotes`

To summarize, it is simply like submitting a form with the having the method post. Except when using ajax it does not require the page to reload.

You may read more about this in my tutorial:
https://www.davidangulo.xyz/website-development/how-to-pass-value-from-javascript-to-php/